# How can I validate a muli page form with html5 required before moving to the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a multi page form that uses div's all in one form. It was originally coded to progress from page to page but did not validate html5 select items only input items, so I striped out the code and now the html5 validation works for all form items but the page no longer progresses to the next page. I tried using checkValidity(); as a check when all items have been filled in but that doesn't seem the be the correct approach. Looking for a way to progress the page and keep the html5 validation intact. [Here is a codepen sample](https://codepen.io/dragonflywebworks/pen/jOOrNmX)

```
function validateForm() {

var $myForm = $('#myForm');

if(!$myForm[0].checkValidity()) {
return false;

}
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I did, I just prevented it from switching to the next tab if the select field had no value...

```
   function nextPrev(n) {
    var st = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
       if (st[0].value==""){ return false;}
       if (st[1].value==""){ return false;}
       if (st[2].value==""){ return false;}
       if (st[3].value==""){ return false;}
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
       if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
       x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
       currentTab = currentTab + n;
      if (currentTab >= x.length) {
           document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
              return false;
               }
                    showTab(currentTab);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the validity of an entire form by getting the form's DOM node and running `checkValidity()` directly on it without the `[0]`.

```
const isValid = document.querySelector('#regForm').checkValidity()

if(isValid) {
   nextSlide()
}
```

You can also add an [`onsubmit`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp) event to your form itself, which will pass in the form as target.

```
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
   <!-- your inputs -->
</form>
```

And your javascript would be something like...

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
   const isValid = e.target.checkValidity()

   if(isValid) {
       nextSlide()
   }
}
```

With this approach your the button inside your form needs to be of `type="submit"`, and you can remove the `onclick` handler from your button.